Iframe accessed via proxy not loading resources from correct address
The setup is as follows:

Docker-compose with several containers, though only two of them are relevant for now:

quasar: The website container, which has a Quasar frontend (via dev server) accessible on the host via localhost:9000 (it also has a backend API at port 5000, but not relevant for now)
knowledge: Second container which exposes another frontend (GraphDB workbench) within the docker network at port 7200



What I want, is to display/embed the frontend provided by container knowledge inside of the frontend of container quasar, using an iframe. Now, the dev server of Quasar comes with HttpProxy middleware, which allows me to reach the containers within the docker network while avoiding CORS issues, which works great for APIs. I had the following configuration for that in quasar.config.ts for the knowledge container:
...
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
    },
    '/kgraph': {
      target: 'http://knowledge:7200',
      changeOrigin: true,
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/kgraph/, ''),
    },
  },
  open: true, // opens browser window automatically
},
...

The second entry there is for the knowledge container. Then, I used the iframe as follows:
    <iframe
      src="/kgraph/graphs-visualizations?uri=http:%2F%2Fwww.semanticweb.org%2Faledpro%2Fontologies%2F2024%2F2%2FuserKG%23Day&embedded"
    ></iframe>

What happens, is that it does indeed load the HTML in the iframe, but then it fails to load all the resources with 404 errors. Upon further inspection, it seems that it tries to load all of the resources from http://localhost:9000, while they reside on http://knowledge:7200. Similarly, all the URLs in the iframe embedding point to localhost:9000.
I checked the script/etc tags of the GraphDB workbench frontend in the knowledge container, and they have src attributes similar to this:
<script charset="utf-8" src="6.0685b09a3646005a1521.bundle.js"></script>

Which doesn't seem to be an absolute path. So regardless of the proxy, it still tries to load resources as if accessed from the current host, instead of respecting the proxy.
I did find a silly way around this, by just not using a proxy and making the GraphDB workbench accessible to the host as well at localhost:7200, and then just using that in the src for the iframe, and that does actually work, but I'd prefer to keep it internal.
So my question is: are there any ways around this problem? Or does it require a completely different approach, e.g. by not using an iframe?

I initially tried getting the page from the backend first and then rewriting all the URLs in the HTML, but even after being able to load most resources, the application remained broken.
But it turns out that the specific front-end that I wanted to have in the iframe (GraphDB workbench) exposes a setting that changes the base URL that determines where to look for resources.
I got inspired to look for this setting by the answer provided here: https://serverfault.com/a/561897
Indeed, GraphDB exposes such a setting, as can be found in the documentation: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/configuring-graphdb.html#url-properties
So in docker-compose, I added the following for the GraphDB container:
entrypoint: 
- "/opt/graphdb/dist/bin/graphdb"
- "-Dgraphdb.external-url=http://localhost:9000/kgraph/"

After adding this, everything loaded as expected.
This seems to be a general pattern for such admin UIs; they usually expose a setting that allows you to change the base path of the application, so it can fetch its resources properly.
